# Converting Multi-Column query into Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two queries that I want to join together, but I don't know how to.

`Select father, mother, guardian from students where user_id = '201209291';`

I get a result of 3 IDs.

Now, I need to use those three IDs to get their personal information;

`Select * from system_users where user_id = (The 3 IDs from the previous query);`

How would i go about solving this problem? I thought of the result of the first query into 3 rows, but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can join directly using a series of `OR`s in the join predicate, as long as the `father`, `mother`, and `guardian` columns are actually `user_id`s in system_users.

```
select usrs.*
from students s 
join system_users usrs on 
    s.father=usrs.user_id OR
    s.mother=usrs.user_id OR
    s.guardian=usrs.user_id
where s.user_id = '201209291';
```

Comment: yes, wanted to add that possibility also to my answer... +1 from me :)

Comment: The only other option is to use a pivot table, which is completely overkill for what is needed. This is probably the simplest way (though I wish you could use something like `IN (s.father, s.mother, s.guardian)` in modern DBMS.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from system_users where user_id IN
(
Select father from students where user_id = '201209291'
UNION
Select mother from students where user_id = '201209291'
UNION
Select guardian from students where user_id = '201209291'
)
```

Comment: Excellent! But I like the join idea more =)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use join?

```
Select father, mother, guardian from students as s
join system_users usrs
on s.user_id=usrs.user_id
where s.user_id = '201209291';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first query you will have not IDs but 3 columns.

`Select father, mother, guardian from students where user_id = '201209291'`.

Probably you mean

`Select distinct some_id from students where user_id = '201209291'`

I suggest simple:

`Select * from system_users where user_id in (Select distinct some_id from students where user_id = '201209291');`

- Did I understand the question correctly?